# NestJS can not show the field with empty list from GRPC response

Tags: node.js, nestjs, grpc, proto

Here is my GRPC response from the server (using blrromRPC):

```
{
  "te": [
    {
      "flags": [],
      "height": 0,
    }
  ]
}
```

The "flags" is an empty list.

However, if I call the same GPRC function in my nestjs project, it would not show the "flags" field (only show the "height"). Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a NestJs problem, the GRPC itself does not have any concept of empty arrays, so empty array are interpreted as undefined.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to let it show the field "flags" in my project (if it is empty)?

Comment: Not that I know of